# Calculating the Moment of Inertia of a Ball (so close)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, moment-of-inertia

So I tried calculating the moment of inertia of a ball (or filled-in sphere) of radius $R$ and mass $M$, and got surprisingly close to the right answer using a simpler approach than I've seen used elsewhere, but I'm wondering where my calculation went wrong.

So I reason that I'm trying to compute $\int_{\text{Region}}r^2\, dm$ and the density $\rho = m/v = \frac{m}{4\pi r^3/3}$ with mass $m$ a function of radius $r$, so $dm = 4\pi r^2\rho\, dr$.  Here mass only depends on $r$ so I only need to integrate with respect to $r$ from 0 to $R$.

$$\int_0^{R}r^2 (4\pi r^2 \rho\, dr) = 4\pi\rho\int_0^Rr^4\, dr$$

$$ = 4\pi\Big(\frac{M}{4\pi R^3/3}\Big)\left(\frac{R^5}{5}\right)$$

$$=\frac{3}{5}MR^2$$

I've followed the calculation of this using cylindrical coordinates and I get that, but I'm just wondering why this method didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We calculate the moment of inertia about an axis of rotation, and the $r$ in the expression $r^2 dm$ refers to the perpendicular distance of a point from the axis. In your integration, however, you have taken it to be the distance of all points from the centre of the sphere, which is on the whole larger than the distance from an axis passing through the centre; you therefore get a result that is larger than the correct answer.

This is also why the correct answer is most conveniently arrived at in cylindrical coordinates - the distance from the axis $r$ appears conveniently as one of the coordinates.

Comment: Yeah to use spherical you have to slice the ball into circles to get the perpendicular radius, makes cylindrical nice for this sort of thing